# Display all labels without collisions in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, labeling, overlapping-features

OpenLayers 6, Mapserver 7

As a beginner, I display polygons like this :

```
const presc = new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  loader: function(extent, resolution, projection, success, failure) {
     // let proj = projection.getCode();
     let url = 'blabla'
     let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open('GET', url);
     let onError = function() {
       presc.removeLoadedExtent(extent);
       failure();
     }
     xhr.onerror = onError;
     xhr.onload = function() {
       if (xhr.status == 200) {
         let features = presc.getFormat().readFeatures(xhr.responseText);
         console.log(features)
         presc.addFeatures(features);
         
         success(features);
       } else {
         onError();
       }
     }
     xhr.send();
   },
   strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
 });
```

and the vector layer :

```
const prescLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: presc,
});
```

For the labels :

```
function stylePresc(feature) { 
    return new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: [250, 100, 80, 0.2]
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: [200, 0, 0, 0.5],
                    width: 1.8
                }),
        text: new ol.style.Text({
                    font: '12px sans-serif',
                    text: feature.get('numoa'),             
        }),
    })
};
```

I have overlapping labels for some polygons with identical geometries but different attributes :
[image]

What is the easiest way to separate them when they are on top of each other? (declutter option is not appropriate)

Comment: You could set `offsetY` on the text style depending on the other attributes

Comment: Following this idea, I have written a function returning a random value for `offsetY` property. The best I can do.